# Double counting in bar charts?

Tags: d3.js, charts

This is not so much a coding question rather than a question on best practices in creating charts.

I have visualized the following data on a bar chart: the total amount of venture capital investments by industry (see screenshot).

What I have done is to allow double counting in the chart, meaning to say, a startup funding round can belong to multiple categories.

I have heard feedback that this is a bad idea, that in bar charts, there should not be double counting of values (so each startup would only belong to one category).

I'm still unconvinced that it's a bad idea though. Perhaps someone can enlighten me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This really isn't a d3/programming question, and should probably be migrated to Cross Validated as a data visualization question.  But I'm here and you're here, so let's give it a go...*

If you do have non-exclusive category data, it is better to use a bar chart than any type of chart (like a pie chart) that implies that all the values add up to a total.

**But** you need to be clear about what you're showing, what the total is and how much duplication there is.

It is common to use bar charts for survey results where the respondent can check off multiple categories.  But the results are always shown as percentages, so it is clear that if you have, for example, 70% of people like ice cream and 60% of people like cake, you know that there is overlap (although you still don't know how much).  Because your chart is based on numbers, not percentages, there isn't even that much clarity.

What you need is a structure that clearly indicates the total amount for all categories, and should also give an idea of the amount that is unique to each category.

One way is to create a new category for "mixed" or "multiple categories".  Then each of your other categories should only include the cases that are *exclusively* in that category, and the mixed value will include the other cases, and everything will only be counted once.

However, if the majority of your cases are "mixed", you could end up losing a lot of information that way.  You'll need to create a custom layout that also contains a breakdown of the different categories within "mixed".

Here's one possible structure for a static image: stack the different categories (here side by side), but also space them out on another dimension (here as separate rows) so that you can show their share of the "multiple categories" total.

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________________
| ECommerce    |    Payments | Games |    Social Media   | Food | Multiple categories |
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|***************                                                 *************        |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                   ~~~~                 |
|                             ########                           ###############      |
|                                     oooooooooooooooooooo       ooooooooooo          |
|                                                         xxxxxxxxx                   |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Another option would be to have a main chart that shows the total (a pie chart, or a stacked bar like the above) without overlap, and then have a regular bar chart that shows percentages (with overlap, and clearly indicating there is overlap):

```
Figure 1: Total Capitalization
 _____________________________________________________________________________________
| ECommerce    |    Payments | Games |    Social Media   | Food | Multiple categories |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
     1M            700K         200K     1.2M               85K        1.8M

Figure 2: Share of funds per category 
   (including projects that fall into multiple categories)

ECommerce:      ****************************    32%
Payments:       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~              25%
Games:          #######################         28%
Social Media:   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo 36%
Food:           xxxxxxxxx                       12%
```

If the graphic is online only, you could also do something interactive so that the breakdown of the "multiple categories" group only shows up on hover/click.